# Why isn't my Canon RC-6 remote control working with my Canon 550D?

Tags: troubleshooting, canon-550d, remote, infrared

I recently bought a Canon RC-6 and got dejected as nothing happened after clicking the button.

The product seems to be working fine with Canon 600D.

Later, I read somewhere the RC6 won't work with Canon- xxD models.[?] Is it true?

Or is it the problem with my Canon 550D IR?

Comment: The RC-6 remote is working fine on my 60D. So, the statement that it does not work on xxD models is not true.

Comment: Canon says it's compatible with the 550D/T2i (as well as most EOS models other than the EOS 1/1D going well back to the film era). Perhaps your IR sensor is faulty/dirty.

Comment: i've it working with 600D

Comment: Mine is working with my 450D... Make sure you use it properly, as Ajhenderson suggested...

Comment: I've got one of those remotes and it works with my 550D. If you have access to a friends 550D, try it with theirs?

Comment: @DarkoZ Seems my IR is faulty.

Answer (score 5):

Instructions for using the RC-6 with your camera can be found on page 204 of your instruction manual.  In order for the remote to work, you must place your camera in the timer/remote shooting mode.  It won't accept IR shutter release unless it is in this mode.

Comment: Tried that. No luck :(

Comment: Ok, only other obvious thing I can think of is check if the battery in the remote is any good.  It's an IR transmitter, so the camera has to be able to see the light on the front of the remote.  If the battery is good and you are sure it is actually firing and you have the camera in the remote shutter mode, then it is possible that your IR receiver in the camera may also have issues.  You may want to contact Canon support if it doesn't turn out to be the battery in the remote.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my Rebel T3i, and through Canon support I found the actual solution.

On the T31, there is a movie mode menu you have to get to.  To do so, you have to first put the camera in movie mode, THEN press the menu key.  When you do that, a movie menu pops up, and one of the items is "Remote."  It will be either enabled or disabled.  So you just have to select "enable" and the problem is solved.

So more generally, it appears that the cameras come with the remote disabled by default.  You just have to get to the movie menu and re-enable it, and you're good to go.

Not sure what the specifics will be to get there on your camera model, but I think in all likelihood the process will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The RC6 works fine with my 550d
Try putting the camera in full auto mode to pick up the sensor also you need to set the shooting mode to self timer/remote control.

Once it picks up the remote from full auto mode you should be good to go on other modes

Answer (score 1):

The RC-6 is an infrared remote, so it works like a TV remote. The remote has to be pointed at the sensor that picks up the IR light signal.  The sensor on Canon dRebels is that circular dot on the front of the grip near the top.  So, it's difficult to use one of these IR remotes correctly from *behind* the camera (for that a cable release tends to be a better tool).

Make sure that the IR sensor is unobstructed and clean. Make sure the remote's IR emitter is pointing directly at the sensor.

Secondly, if you're using it outdoors, in bright sunlight, the IR signal can be overwhelmed (or at least be much more difficult for the sensor to pick up) by the ambient light levels being so high. These remotes often work better when used indoors in lower light conditions. Both the range and reliability of the signal can be compromised when used outdoors because not only is the ambient light so much higher, but there are probably no bounce surfaces for the IR signal to get back to the sensor--so the line-of-sight requirements get more stringent.  The only way around these issues is to switch to radio triggers.